# Javascript Get JSON data from Url via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following setup:
Two local domains 192.168.30.1 -> Webserver with the JSON data and 169.254.168.105:3000 where I want to work with the data.

The webserver displays the data via php and you have to be authenticated to see the data. So the url looks like this: "http://192.168.30.1/rest/activity14?auth_username=username&auth_password=password"
And if I enter this in a browser a get the following output:

```
{
    people: [
        {
            id: "58107d10ad910",
            name: "name"
        }
    ],
    documents: [
        {
            document_id: "5811f9b306216",
            name: "document1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to work with this on the other domain. So I tried to get the data via jQuery ajax but it seems that I can't get it no matter what. I tried the following ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: $url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("success" );
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log("Error: " + e);
    }
});
```

which results in an error in the console ("Error: [object Object]").

So I tried around with different approaches. I tried getJSON:

```
$.getJSON( $url, function(data) {
    console.log("success");
}).error(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

which didn't even give an error message.

I also read about jsonp and using it for cross domain json calls. The following approach

```
function logResults(json) {
    console.log("json" + json);
}

$.ajax({
    url: $url + "callback=logResults?",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "logResults",
    error: function(e) {
        console.log("Error: " + e);
    }
});
```

which didn't work either. In the deloper tools network tab I found the following about the jsonp call (status: cancelled):

```
General:
Request URL:http://192.168.30.1/rest/activity14?    auth_username=kusername&auth_password=password&callback=logResults?&callback=logResults&_=1478083606031

Request Headers:
Provisional headers are shown
Referer:http://169.254.168.105:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36

Query String Parameters:
auth_username:username
auth_password:password
callback:logResults?
callback:logResults
_:1478083606031
```

I can't really interpret this, but maybe it helps finding my problem.

What would be the right approach for my specific case and if I was already on the right way what did I do wrong in the end?

Edit:
Here is the output in the DevTools network tab for the normal JSON request (not the jsonp request):

```
General:
Request URL:https://rippleapi.herokuapp.com/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=http%3A//192.168.33.10/rest/activity14%3Fauth_username%3Dusername%26auth_password%3Dpassword

Request Headers:
Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Request-Headers:x-ripple-user-agent
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Origin:http://169.254.168.105:3000
Referer:http://169.254.168.105:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36

Query String Parameters:
tinyhippos_apikey:ABC
tinyhippos_rurl:http://192.168.33.10/rest/activity14?auth_username=username&auth_password=password
```

Comment: The `getJSON` version doesn't give error because the promise version of *error* is `fail` method, not `error`. Also, try to `console.log` the `e` itself, not concatenating it to `"Error: "`. I mean something like `console.log("Error", e)` would do it. Then you can check the error object in the console and have a better idea what's happening.

Comment: @kk_, you said that when you're using first method of `AJAX` you get `Error: [object Object]`. That means you're response goes on the error callback. Then most probably means that is something wrong with the serverside code.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási I changed the error console.log and the output is "Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}" which doesn't really help right?

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Do you mean I should just enter the url in a browser with "run the PHP script"? I did this and the output is the JSON return I posted in the question.

Comment: Oh I see thanks, didn't realize it. Did you check if `$url` variable  is correct?

Comment: Have you checked the normal JSON request in the DevTools Network tab? How does it appear?

Comment: Also, note that you have two `?` in the request URL, you can see the effect in the PHP output, there are two `callback` variables, one with a `?` at the end. This is (I think) because you don't need to add the callback parameter manually, jQuery will do it.

Comment: I console.log the $url variable and it is correct. I deleted the "&callback=?" and now there's only one in the network tab. So you're right, it does add the callback automatically.

Comment: I edited the devtools network output for the normal json request in the question

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint that you are querying should return encoded object not a parsed one. If you are using PHP, try `json_encode()`

Comment: So beforehand, I didn't write the PHP controller that sends the JSON data (I can change it though). But with what I can see, this is already happening. The Zend framework is in use and a method "$this->sendJson(['people' => $people, 'documents' => $documents]);" is called. And with what I can see, this part is the same as json_encode() (https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html Quote: "Usage is simple: either call it as a method of the helper broker, or call one of the methods encodeJson() or sendJson()")

Comment: 1.I copied your browser output and ran a JSON.stringify() function on it. The result is different from what you list:

`{"people":[{"id":"58107d10ad910","name":"name"}],"documents":[{"document_id":"5811f9b306216","name":"document1"}]}
`. 2.When you log things `console.log('error' + e)`, it would be better if you log `console.log('error', e)`  - coma instead of plus, otherwsie the error get's converted to string [Object object] instead of showing actual object. Maybe that will give us more information about actual error. You can also see request response in the browser, before JS

Comment: To 1.) Sorry, I didn't mention that my output was modified by a chrome plugin ("JSON View" - I didn't know that it changes the syntax). I disabled it and get exactly the same output you posted now: {"people":[{"id":"58107d10ad910","name":"name"}],"documents":[{"document_id":"5811f9b306216","name":"document1"}]} To 2.) I changed it earlier yesterday and this is the output of the object: "Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}" - but I think this doesn't really help either